# parameter is modified after scanf

Tags: c

I'm pretty new to c and I've been finding that after using the scanf function my char *string parameter gets modified, the input to c doesn't change the end output nor does the actual parameter. though it does seem what comes next in the code does change the final output. i can't find any example of this happening online does anybody know what this is? my only thought is that im missing something but i can't see what it is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int method1(char *string){
    char c;
    printf("enter(y/n): ");
    scanf("%s", &c);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char *string = "string";
    printf("%s\n", string);
    method1(string);
    return 0;
}
```

output:
string
enter(y/n): y                                                                  ▒E▒

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c` can hold just a single char. But

```
scanf("%s", &c);
```

will read multiple characters and there's no room for that in `c`. Hence, it's [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
Even if you input just 1 char, `%s` will still require a space for the terminating null byte.

If you just want to read a single character then you can use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) as below:

```
char c[2];
if (fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin)) {
  /* c[0] contains your input 'y' or 'n' */
}
```

Always avoid `scanf()`. See: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)